# Plot a data in a graph by one value and an errorbar by another

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, standard-deviation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID      B    Group
 0     120     5  
 1     122     5  
 2     119     5  
 3     100     4  
 4     099     4  
 5     105     4  
 6     099     3  
 7     098     3  
 8     099     3
...            ...
```

The values in "B" can be associated to a group "Group" whose numbers are ordered and are descending but do not always have the same occurrence. For example "Group" 5 could appear three times, but "Group" 2 could appear seven times. Every "Group" appears at least once.
Now I want to use "Group" as x-axis and "B" as y-axis parameter with error bars. The error bar max should be the maximum of each group and the min the minimum of each group. The graph I show you now, is just an example of how the graph should look like in the end.

[image]

As library I use "ggplot", I got told that it is not the best suiting library for what I want to achieve, but as a beginner, it is the only one I know a bit.
My code so far looks like this:

```
require("ggplot2")
pplot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Group, y=B))
pplot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Group, ymin=Group ), width= 0.1)
```

My solution seems wrong, and does not work as I expexted. I don't know how to feed the function with the max and min correctly.
My question now is how to make a graph like the one you see above with "B" as y-axis and "Group" as x-axis, and is it even possible to use the function "geom_errorbar()" for this?

As a next step I plan to draw a "geom_line" with the average of each "Group" as a point on it. But one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear since the values of your B axis in your graph do not match your table. Nevertheless, for error bars over B with A as group, that's the way (assuming you want SDs - but with the method you can pretty much compute what you want):

```
 vec.sd <- tapply(data$B,data$group,sd)
 vec.mean <- tapply(data$B,data$group,sd)
 plot(X,Y)
 arrows(x0=data$A,x1=data$A,y0=vec.mean-vec.sd,y1=vec.mean+vec.sd,code=3,angle=90,length=0.08)
```

Comment: The picture is one I found online, but describes what I want. I just changed the name of the axis to A and B.

Comment: Ok. Well tell me if my answer helps you. I figured afterwards maybe you specifically wish to do it with ggplot2::ggplot?

Comment: I get an error in your first two lines: Error in tapply(data$B, data$group, sd) : arguments must have same length

Comment: The column with the "group" does not exist yet. I don't know how to put each line into a group.

Comment: Well you need a column that contains the group. You can create it if you know how to determine your group (based on values). 'tapply' should work, here is an exemple using a R builtin dataset: 'df = datasets::airquality; tapply(df$Wind,df$Month,sd) ' will yield sd of Wind for each Month. If that doesn't help, then just explain how you want to recover your groups with your dataset

Comment: Thats a bit tricky because the data I get is always around a certain value and never perfect. For example the first group would contain everything around 5.0 the second one 4.9 the third 4.8 and so on.

Comment: Just ‘df[df$B < 4.9 & df$B > 4.8,] = group1’

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I added a new column "Group" and gave row a 
data["Group"] <- NA
data[(data$A>4.95), "Group"] <- 5.0
data[(data$A>4.85 & data$A<4.95), "Group"] <- 4.9
And so on.
Now I am stuck at the errorbar. I don't know how I can extract the min and max of each Group. My idea looks like this:
pplot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = maxOfEachGroup, ymin=minOfEachGroup), width= 0.1)

Comment: If you are talking about the 'min(data$A)' and 'max(data$A)' based on groups defined by 'data$B'. Then: 'ymin = as.vector(tapply(data$A,data$B,min))' 'ymax = as.vector(tapply(data$A,data$B,max))'. Let me know if that's what you need and if it works, I will edit your question and post it all together as one answer you can accept or not.

Comment: Yes I would like to use the max and min of each group as error range.
If I add your code: pplot_RSSI <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B))
pplot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = as.vector(tapply(data$Group, data$A,min)), ymax = as.vector(tapply(data$Group,data$A,max))
), width= 0.1)  I get the following error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data : ymin, ymax, x,y

Comment: Yes that's because you have more values of A than groups, therefore you are sending less intervals than there are points. If I get what you are asking for, i thing you rather want to do a plot with Group as your x-axis and B as your Y-axis. I would drop the ggplot (why do you wish to use ggplot? What you are asking for is quite unusual and ggplot will not get the logic). And go for plot and arrows (posted above). You can enter my tapply answer in that arrow function

Comment: I ask for that because I am a beginner with R and ggplot was the first library I used for plotting.

Comment: I did what you suggested and used "Group" for the x-axis and "B" for the y-axis but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the deviation of B for each "group" with the errorbar plot, the x position need to be the "group", and the y value need to be the min(B) and max(B) for each group. It doesn't matter with the value A, so to draw the errorbar plot , you need first to transform your data, a sample code may like that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 5),
                   y = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                   group = sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 50, replace = TRUE))

data_groupby <- data%>%group_by(group)%>%
  summarise(ymin  = min(y), ymax = max(y))

ggplot(data_groupby, aes(x = group))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))+
  theme_bw()
```

[errorbar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS8TO.png)

however, I think the best plot type for your purpose, may using the **Boxplot**.

Comment: What does "%>%" mean? If I try it, I get following error:  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: "%>%" is a function which support pipeline operations in R. You can learn more about the pipeline function from [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package and [wrappr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wrapr/index.html) package.